# is there a way to 2 create multiple command files in cypress

Tags: cypress

To manage or to have more structures format i would like to create multiple commands files based on different pages i have in the application. would it be really possible to create multiple commands files, if yes how we should? else how we can manage all the page scenarios in one commands file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the default `cypress/support/index.js` file you'll see a line like this:

```
import "./commands";
```

This adds the commands from the `cypress/support/commands.js` file.

You can similarly add a `cypress/support/someOtherCommands.js` file and import it in the `cypress/support/index.js` file by adding this line:

```
import "./someotherCommands";
```

You can add as many of those as you want, you could also nest them in directories for better structure. Example:  `cypress/support/settings/mainSettingsPage.js` would be imported with:

```
import "./settings/mainSettingsPage";
```

Comment: awesome, this is exactly im looking for.